# Jenkins Job Builder failing authentication with Jenkins due to encoding issue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I'm trying to run `jenkins-jobs update` for the first time on my system, but it fails on authentication.

#### Command:

`jenkins-jobs --conf ./jjb.ini update jobs/`

Where `jobs` contains a `test.yml` - a miniature build project just for testing. `jjb.ini` is:

```
[jenkins]
user=admin
password={{ admin_api_token }} # Inserted API token here.
url=http://127.0.0.1:8080
query_plugins_info=False
```

#### Expected result:

Success, and import of the example build project into Jenkins.

#### Actual result:

```
INFO:jenkins_jobs.cli.subcommand.update:Updating jobs in ['jobs/'] ([])
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Number of jobs generated:  1
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 557, in jenkins_request
    self._request(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 508, in _response_handler
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Invalid password/token for user: b'admin' for url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json
```

What catches my eye here is that the authentication fails for `b'admin`, not for `admin`. This is also reflected in the "People" page on Jenkins web-interface, which before the attempted login only showed `admin`, but after the attempted login shows:

[image]

From what I've been able to figure out, there may be a problem with encoding in the login request from JJB, but I'm looking for help when it comes to how to go about trying to fix this.

#### Current setup:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Jenkins 2.125 (working as expected, at :8080)
jenkins-job-builder 2.0.9 
Python 3.5.2
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-10.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip (python 3.5)
java -version: openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
```

Answer (score 3):

It works with requests==2.19.1

`sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo pip install requests
$ pip freeze | grep requests
requests==2.19.1`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.

Comment: For now, the version is 2.22.0. You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps resolved the issue in my case:

```
pip3.7 freeze | grep requests 

pip3.7 uninstall requests

pip3.7 install requests

pip3.7 freeze | grep requests
```

Comment: Please avoid the impression of saying thanks for an existing answer (which I am pretty sure you are not, though maybe only adding some little, but valuable, detail..). E.g. by adding an explanation on how this works and why it helps.